# How to install/load an R library under a user specified namespace?

Tags: r

#### Question

How can a library be installed/loaded under a different namespace, so that its functions can be called from that alternate namespace.

#### Simple example

E.g.

```r
library(dplyr, namespace="example_namespace")
```

which would in turn allow

```r
example_namespace::setdiff()
example_namespace::arrange()
# etc
```

#### Why?

Suppose I had 4 `.tar.gz` files of the same package that were nearly identical but for some minor changes to a function which I want to test. It could be handy to be able to load all 4 versions at the same time, and test each function, like so

```
first_namespace::my_func()
second_namespace::my_func()
third_namespace::my_func()
fourth_namespace::my_func()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the package with a command like this:

```
install.packages("pkg.tar.gz", "custom/path", repos = NULL)
```

Then you should be able to load it like this:

```
library(pkg, lib.loc = c("custom/path", .libPaths()))
```

But I don't think you can load all of them at the same time.
R simply won't load a package that's already loaded,
and I believe it uses the name specified in `DESCRIPTION` as only source.

Comment: Great solution. It works (had to close/reopen Rstudio because I had a package of the same name already loaded).

Comment: @user5783745 cleaning workspace and pressing Ctrl+Shift+F10 should leave you in a clean R session.